# How to send data client to server django channel

Tags: java, django, python-3.x, django-channels, ws

Hi all I'm trying send data js to django with websocket but not working Could you help me where am I doing wrong?

ps: I was able to send data from the server to the client

error:

> raise ValueError("No text section for incoming WebSocket frame!")
>
> No text section for incoming WebSocket frame!
>
> WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/ [127.0.0.1:64282]

js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let webSocketBridge = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/");

        webSocketBridge.onopen = function(action) {
            console.log(action);
            webSocketBridge.send(JSON.stringify({
                "id": "client1"
            }));

        };

        webSocketBridge.onmessage = function(event) {
           let message = event.data;
            as += message + "\r\n";
            $('#messages').html(as);

        };
```

consumer.py

```
import asyncio
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer

class TickTockConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

        while 1:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            await self.send_json("tick")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            await self.send_json(".......tock")
            await self.receive()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
class TickTockConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send("tick")
        self.send(".......tock")

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)
```

or with async json

```
class TickTockConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.send("tick")
        await self.send(".......tock")

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)
```